# JOIN em postgres não traz todos os dados desejados

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando fazer um JOIN entre a tabela A e B, e quando faço:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_A JOIN tabela_B ON tabela_a.id=tabela_b.id
```

Dá certo, tenho todos os dados de ambas as tabelas reunidos.

Todavia, quando filtro colunas especificas da tabela A, exemplo:

```
SELECT coluna_a FROM tabela_A JOIN tabela_B ON tabela_a.id=tabela_b.id
```

Os únicos dados retornados são essa coluna_a da tabela_A.

Testei com várias tabelas e com outros tipos de JOIN tipo Left, right, inner, e ainda sim o único retorno que tenho é a coluna filtrada.

Como faço para ter a coluna específica da tabela A + toda a tabela B?

Answer (score -2):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é declarando um `alias` para cada tabela e depois exibindo as colunas desejadas. Isso é possível da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT b.*, a.coluna_especifica FROM tabela_1 a JOIN tabela_2 b ON a.id=b.id
```

> Nesta consulta eu desejo exibir todas as colunas da tabela_2 (e dei um
> alias chamado ***b*** para esta tabela) e desejo apenas  exibir uma
> coluna específica da tabela_1 (que dei um alias chamado ***a*** para
> esta tabela).

Desta forma um nome temporário pode ser dado a uma tabela para fazer referências a dados derivados das tabelas no resto da consulta. Isto é chamado de alias.

Existem duas sintaxes possíveis para declarar um alias de tabela (abaixo um destaque da sintaxe no `FROM`:

```
FROM table_reference AS alias
```

ou

```
FROM table_reference alias
```

Para o caso desta resposta escolhi utilizei a segunda sintaxe exibida por ser mais concisa.

Para mais exemplos de uso [consulte a documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html).